# How to create drag-drop labels report in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, report

I'm intending to create a dynamic report in my ASP .NET MVC application that users can design some features on report by themselves. I mean users can upload their background image, choose some labels from a fixed set of some specific properties that can be got from server, set their position. And last of all, when user click to Export button, the request would be send to servers, servers then receive the request that contains which properties was added and their position. And then servers get data from database and fill out the report and return report file to users.

I don't know which technologies or frameworks in ASP.NET MVC can help me to do that. I was wondering if you guys help me listing all technologies can and their price/

Answer (score 0):

I saw such example by Fast Report: [ASP MVC razor report](https://www.fast-report.com:2015/razor/) (click on "labels report")
with online designer on JS: [online report designer](https://www.fast-report.com:2015/razor/Home/Designer).

But may be you need some "step by step wizard"?